# Wordpress Plugin leaking memory

Tags: amazon-ec2, memory-leaks, wordpress

I have a website running on Wordpress. I am running the website on Amazon EC2 web servers, with t2.micro instance. (1CPU and 1GB RAM).

I have installed a few plugins and one of them is leaking memory and overloading the main memory of the system and also the swap space of the system. I am unable to determine which plugin is leaking the memory.

Is there a way to determine what wordpress plugin is leaking memory? or if anyone is familiar with plugins listed below that have cause the same problem for you?

```
 ubuntu@sdf:/var/www/html/wordpress/wp-content/plugins$ ls
360-product-rotation     cm-map-locations
hello.php          live-composer-page-builder   
revslider            store-locator-le        
woocommerce_events    wp-mail-smtp             
wysija-newsletters   akismet               
contact-form-7         html5-responsive-faq  
mailpoet-woocommerce-add-on      shortcodes-ultimate             
the-events-calendar      woocommerce-menu-bar-cart  
wpmandrill               yith-woocommerce-zoom-magnifier
breadcrumb-navxt      ds-live-composer    index.php             
market-360-viewer            showcase-visual-composer-addon  
Ultimate_VC_Addons   wordpress-seo              wp-post-formats-develop
breadcrumbs           flexi-pages-widget  js_composer           _notes                       
smart-product-viewer            woocommerce          wpglobus      wp-super-cache
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this plugin, it will show you your answer: [p3 profiler](https://es.wordpress.org/plugins/p3-profiler/)